# Software to manage my book collection

Tags: ebooks, books

Is there any software letting me manage my book collection and sync it with anobii or any other online reading community?

---

aNobii is an online reading community built by readers for readers allowing you to shelve, find and share books. Our mission is to bring book lovers together and encourage reading.

Comment: you mean both books and ebooks as the tags suggest?

Answer (score 2):

There is an [API for aNobii](http://www.anobii.com/api_home) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/anobiiapi/) is software using that API.
But that is about it ... to use this on Ubuntu you still need a script/GUI and I have not found anything but this. So the answer for now is: No.

Another approach for books without an e: aNobii can use the barcode on the back of a book. So get a barcode reader, attach it to your system and scan books while you are on the website. Of course you can also do this with your phone but that is off topic unless it is a Ubuntu phone :+)

Comment: thank you very much for the answers. At least is there any software like calibre I can use to manage my paper books library on ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about anobii, but I use calibre (`sudo apt-get install calibre`) for managing/converting my ebooks.

Comment: he is probably talking about normal books ;)

Comment: Nooo the ones made of paper ;)

Comment: damn missed that :D I love calibre  too ;)